# elements not getting added in list groovy script

Tags: groovy

The weird thing is happening while adding elements in list in groovy.
Scenario-
There are two List list1 and list2. List1 contains Object of X type and List2 is empty. List1 is getting populated from java file and while iterating List1 in groovy script, I am adding objects in List2.

But what happening is elements are not getting added. List2 remains empty. 
If I debug the line and evaluate the expression/line it then it is getting added. But while normal debugging while executing this line, it suddenly jump to any random line. 
No exception is coming.

Have created list as below:

```
List<X> dataToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>()
```

Iterating the list as below:

```
for (X data in XList) {
    if(something) {
        dataToBeRemoved.add(data)
    }
}
```

I am new to Groovy and If any one have ever faced this kind of issue. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: `add(X)` seems be type, not value

Comment: sorry it was data. I have updated post.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't ask, but type parameters don't get you much.

```
List elementsToRemove = []
```

And, in this case even better:

```
List elementsToRemove = allElements.findAll { ...some condition... }
```

After that, it's impossible to tell from your code. Questions such as "Why doesn't Groovy work?" are hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the an empty list by simply using

`def mySmallList = []`

and you may also use findAll to filter out the list

`mySmallList = myBigList.findAll {//some condition }`

Please check the link https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5127180895911936